# Get the results to show up on the same row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My script is outputting two rows for each product one row for 'Sold' and the other for 'Inventory'. What I want is to group these by product so only one row appears for each product. I'm using the WHERE statement to show just one product to test. Once I can get it working properly I will remove the WHERE statement.

This is my code:

```
SELECT Product_Name, sum(Product_Sold) AS 'Sold', CASE WHEN Item_sold = 0 THEN sum(Product_Inventory) END AS 'Inventory' 
FROM Products 
WHERE Product = 'TOY' 
group by Product_Name
```

Result of this is:

```
    Sold    Inventory
TOY 10000   
TOY         10000
```

What I want is:

```
    Sold    Inventory
TOY 10000   10000
```

Comment: (1) Your query should generate an error, because you have an unaggregated column.  (2) Show sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Product_Name, sum(Product_Sold) AS Sold, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Item_sold = 0 THEN Product_Inventory END) AS Inventory 
FROM Products 
WHERE Product = 'TOY' 
GROUP BY Product_Name;
```

Your stated query should return an error because `Item_sold` is not the argument to an aggregation function and is not a `GROUP BY` key.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, just tried that out and it seems be working perfectly. I believe it did show up and error so I added Item_sold to the GROUP BY. I just forgot to add this to the query above.

Answer (score 0):

Try sum each rows and not use case with sum()

```
    SELECT Product_Name, sum(Product_Sold) AS 'Sold', 
       sum ( CASE WHEN Item_sold = 0 then Product_Inventory else 0 end) AS 'Inventory' 
FROM Products 
WHERE Product = 'TOY' 
group by Product_Name
```